# Simple query not returning blank records

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, empty-string

Very simple example here to a very frustrating treasure hunt for the mystery character.

I have a table with a `varchar(1) NOT NULL` column - everything default - `ANSI_PADDING` & `NULLS` are `ON` for the table as well. We'll call this column `CodeNum`

A simple query would be

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA
WHERE CodeNum = ' '
```

If I run this query against DatabaseA  it returns the all the rows that have a blank or "nothing" in the column as expected.

If I run the same query against DatabaseB for the same table (used compare scripts and even tools to verify they are the same) it returns no results.

I tried looking for hidden carriage returns and other characters by looking for `CHAR(1)` through `CHAR(255)`. Still no results.

As a test I tried setting the column in DatabaseB equal to `''` with a blanket update statement.

```
UPDATE tableA
SET CodeNum = ''
```

Now my query returns the results as expected. So to me that says that there is some character in that column but I'd really like to figure out what that character is so I can track down its origin. Any thoughts on what else I could be missing?

Comment: Dumb question: why `varchar` and not `char`? Why no check constraint to prevent space, tab, cr, lf, or basically anything outside the domain of code numbers you want to allow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT ASCII(CodeNum)
FROM tableA
```

To see the ascii number of the character in that field.